# React-Firebase: Why does page fail on first load, but then loads properly on refresh?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a react project that is pulling data from a firebase back end. When I load the page rendering my `GigRegister` component, I get the following error:

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'uid' of null
```

....but when I refresh the page, it loads as it should. Any ideas as to why? Here's the code for my `GigRegister` component:

```
import React from "react";
    import Header from "./Header";
    import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
    import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
    import axios from "axios";
    import * as firebase from 'firebase'
    import { auth } from 'firebase/app'
    import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
    import UniqueVenueListing from './UniqueVenueListing'


    class GigRegister extends React.Component {
      constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
          name: "",
          venue: "",
          time: "",
          date: "",
          genre: "",
          tickets: "",
          price: "",
          userDetails:{},
          filterGigs:[]
        };
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
      }

      handleChange(e) {
        this.setState({
          [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
        });
      }
    
      handleClick(){
        console.log('handle click reached')
        auth().signOut().then(() => {
          console.log('Successfully signed out')
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err)
        })
      }



      authListener(){
        auth().onAuthStateChanged((user)=>{
          if(user){
            this.setState({
              userDetails: user
            })
            axios.get("https://us-central1-gig-fort.cloudfunctions.net/api/getGigListings")
            .then(res=> {
              let filteredGigs = res.data
              .filter(gig => {
                return gig.user === this.state.userDetails.uid
              })
              this.setState({
                filterGigs: filteredGigs
              })
            })
          } else {
            this.setState({
              userDetails: null
            })
            console.log('no user signed in')
          }
        })
      }

      componentDidMount(){
        this.authListener()
      }

      handleSubmit(e) {
        let user = auth().currentUser.uid

        const gigData = {
          name: this.state.name,
          venue: this.state.venue,
          time: this.state.time,
          date: this.state.date,
          genre: this.state.genre,
          tickets: this.state.tickets,
          price: this.state.price,
          user:user
        };
        
        
        auth().currentUser.getIdToken().then(function(token) {
          axios("http://localhost:5000/gig-fort/us-central1/api/createGigListing", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
              "content-type": "application/json",
              "Authorization": "Bearer "+token,
            },
            data: gigData,
          })
      })
          .then((res) => {
            console.log(res);
            this.props.history.push('/Homepage')
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.error(err);
          });
      }
    
    
      render() {
        return (
          <div className="gig-register">
            <Header />
            <div className = 'heading-container'>
              <h1>Venue Dashboard</h1> <br></br>
              {
              this.state.userDetails ?
              <h3>You are signed in as {this.state.userDetails.email}</h3>
              :
              null
              }
              <div className = 'gig-reg-buttons'>
                {
                this.state.userDetails ?
                <Button onClick = {this.handleClick}>Sign out </Button>
                :
                <Link to = '/' style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}>
                  <Button>Sign In</Button>
                </Link>
                }
                <Link to="/Homepage" style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}>
                <Button>Go to gig listings</Button>
                </Link>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className = 'handle-gigs'>
                <div className = 'reg-gig-input'>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                  <h3>Register a gig</h3>
                  <br></br>
              <TextField
                placeholder="Event name"
                defaultValue="Event name"
                id="name"
                name="name"
                onChange={this.handleChange}
              />
              <TextField
                placeholder="Time"
                defaultValue="Time"
                type="time"
                label="Enter start time"
                id="time"
                name="time"
                InputLabelProps={{
                  shrink: true,
                }}
                inputProps={{
                  step: 300, // 5 min
                }}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
              />
              <TextField
                id="date"
                label="Select date"
                type="date"
                defaultValue="2017-05-24"
                InputLabelProps={{
                  shrink: true,
                }}
                onChange={(e) => {
                  this.setState({ date: e.target.value });
                }}
              />
              <TextField
                placeholder="Genre"
                defaultValue="Genre"
                id="genre"
                name="genre"
                onChange={this.handleChange}
              />
              <TextField
                placeholder="Tickets"
                defaultValue="Tickets"
                id="tickets"
                name="tickets"
                onChange={this.handleChange}
              />
              <TextField
                placeholder="Price"
                defaultValue="Price"
                id="price"
                name="price"
                onChange={this.handleChange}
              />
              <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
            </form>
                </div>
                <div className = 'manage-gigs'>
                  <h3 className = 'manage-gig'>Manage your gigs</h3>
                  <br></br>
                  { this.state.userDetails ?
                    <UniqueVenueListing gigList = {this.state.filterGigs}/>
                    :
                    <h2>no gigs to show</h2>
                  }
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
    
    export default GigRegister
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're not logged in yet on the first page load. When you first load this component on your app your browser still hasn't checked with Firebase if you're logged in or not, so on that very first render `currentUser` will be undefined.

It's an easy fix though. As an example, just have a state variable, say `userIsLoggedIn` tracking the login status, which will start out as undefined. On the callback in `onAuthStateChanged` you can set it to either true or false, depending on whether authentication was successful or not.

Then, if userIsLoggedIn is undefined, you can show a message like "Authenticating...", if it's false you show a login form, and if its true you get on with your app knowing your used is logged in properly and currentUser.uid has a value.

Here's the [offical documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start) on this, by the way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Does this mean that I'd have to move my auth listener from my GigRegister component to my login component? Because at the moment they're two seperate things.

Comment: @JoshSimon you don't have to per se, as long as you deal with the fact that currentUser might be undefined within GigRegister. It might be simpler and cleaner to have an Auth component though, one that depending on the authentication state will render a loading indicator component, a login component or the GigRegister component. There's no right way to do it though, just make sure you understand the problem at hand and pick whichever solution works best for you :)

Comment: I get what you're saying - that I need to keep track of auth status in state, and then render things based on that status - jsut not sure how to implement it. Could I trouble you for a code example?